# Python encoding/decoding problems

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, ascii, non-ascii-characters

How do I decode strings such as this one "weren\xe2\x80\x99t" back to the normal encoding.

So this word is actually weren't and not "weren\xe2\x80\x99t"? 
    For example:

```
print "\xe2\x80\x9cThings"
string = "\xe2\x80\x9cThings"
print string.decode('utf-8')
print string.encode('ascii', 'ignore')

â€œThings
“Things
Things
```

But I actually want to get "Things.

or:

```
print "weren\xe2\x80\x99t"
string = "weren\xe2\x80\x99t"
print string.decode('utf-8')
print string.encode('ascii', 'ignore')

werenâ€™t
weren’t
werent
```

But I actually want to get weren't.

How should i do this?

Comment: You'll need to provide your desired translation dictionary -- e.g from fancy quotes to plain ASCII ones -- and use the `.translate` method of Unicode strings to apply it.  I don't think there is a standard "asciify it down" translation dictionary around...

Comment: Well, i just made one :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I mapped the most common strange chars so this is pretty much complete answer based on the Oliver W. answer.

This function is by no means ideal,but it is the best place to start with.
There are more  chars definitions:

http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128&utf8=string
 http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&names=-&utf8=string-literal

...

```
def unicodetoascii(text):

    uni2ascii = {
            ord('\xe2\x80\x99'.decode('utf-8')): ord("'"),
            ord('\xe2\x80\x9c'.decode('utf-8')): ord('"'),
            ord('\xe2\x80\x9d'.decode('utf-8')): ord('"'),
            ord('\xe2\x80\x9e'.decode('utf-8')): ord('"'),
            ord('\xe2\x80\x9f'.decode('utf-8')): ord('"'),
            ord('\xc3\xa9'.decode('utf-8')): ord('e'),
            ord('\xe2\x80\x9c'.decode('utf-8')): ord('"'),
            ord('\xe2\x80\x93'.decode('utf-8')): ord('-'),
            ord('\xe2\x80\x92'.decode('utf-8')): ord('-'),
            ord('\xe2\x80\x94'.decode('utf-8')): ord('-'),
            ord('\xe2\x80\x94'.decode('utf-8')): ord('-'),
            ord('\xe2\x80\x98'.decode('utf-8')): ord("'"),
            ord('\xe2\x80\x9b'.decode('utf-8')): ord("'"),

            ord('\xe2\x80\x90'.decode('utf-8')): ord('-'),
            ord('\xe2\x80\x91'.decode('utf-8')): ord('-'),

            ord('\xe2\x80\xb2'.decode('utf-8')): ord("'"),
            ord('\xe2\x80\xb3'.decode('utf-8')): ord("'"),
            ord('\xe2\x80\xb4'.decode('utf-8')): ord("'"),
            ord('\xe2\x80\xb5'.decode('utf-8')): ord("'"),
            ord('\xe2\x80\xb6'.decode('utf-8')): ord("'"),
            ord('\xe2\x80\xb7'.decode('utf-8')): ord("'"),

            ord('\xe2\x81\xba'.decode('utf-8')): ord("+"),
            ord('\xe2\x81\xbb'.decode('utf-8')): ord("-"),
            ord('\xe2\x81\xbc'.decode('utf-8')): ord("="),
            ord('\xe2\x81\xbd'.decode('utf-8')): ord("("),
            ord('\xe2\x81\xbe'.decode('utf-8')): ord(")"),

                            }
    return text.decode('utf-8').translate(uni2ascii).encode('ascii')

print unicodetoascii("weren\xe2\x80\x99t")
```

Answer (score 5):

In Python 3 I would do it like this:

```
string = "\xe2\x80\x9cThings"
bytes_string = bytes(string, encoding="raw_unicode_escape")
happy_result = bytes_string.decode("utf-8", "strict")
print(happy_result)
```

No translation maps needed, just code :)

Comment: I was looking for this answer!

Comment: Is there such solution for python 2.7.5?

Comment: Hi @SudiptaRoy do you have a possibility to update to Python 3.x ? If so, I would strongly recommend that. I do not have a Python 2.7.5 available, but I would strongly guess that the following code would work. No guarantees, but fingers crossed! string = u"\xe2\x80\x9cThings"; bytes_string = str(string, encoding="raw_unicode_escape"); print(happy_result)

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a translation map that maps unicode characters to other unicode characters (the latter should be within the ASCII range if you want to re-encode to it):

```
uni2ascii = {ord('\xe2\x80\x99'.decode('utf-8')): ord("'")}    
yourstring.decode('utf-8').translate(uni2ascii).encode('ascii')
print(yourstring)  # prints: "weren't"
```

Comment: I know that i can do this. But is there a ready map that can do this automatically?